# xamarin NavigationView gives error no resource found for app:headerLayout

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross, android-appcompat

I am trying to set up the NavigationView in my Xamarin Android project. I have the Main.axml file structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navmenu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/headerdrawerlayout" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

in my packages.config, I have the AppCompat packages (among others):

```
<package id="MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat" version="4.1.7" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
<package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
```

I get the compiler error:

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout' in package 'mycompany.myapp'  myapp.Android   C:\Users\JP\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyApp\MyApp.Android\Resources\layout\Main.axml
```

Shouldn't the Resource.designer.cs file automatically bring in these attributes? I must admit to being a little bit unsure of how that process works. Could it be a version conflict somewhere? How does the res-auto fit into everything?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your build target is high enough for the correct resources to be included. What are your targets in your app and what compiler level are you using?

Comment: Compile Using: Android 6, Minimum Android: 4.0.3 API 15, Target Android: 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have Android Design Support Library installed.

You can get it via [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/) (or [Xamarin Component store](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportdesign)):

```
Install-Package Xamarin.Android.Support.Design
```

The `DrawerLayout` is a feature of Android Support Library with a dependency on the Design Support Library as it is a material design control. Many of the Android Support Libraries do not have a hard dependency on the Design Support Library due to the fact that supporting material design on pre API 21 (Lollipop) is optional. However, with respect to the `DrawerLayout` it is a [required despency](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/index.html#layout-patterns).

> Support libraries provide user interface elements not offered by the
>   Android framework. For example, the Android Support Library offers
>   additional layout classes, like DrawerLayout. These classes follow
>   recommended Android design practices; for example, the Design Library
>   follows the principles of material design in a way that works across
>   many versions of Android.

**How `headerLayout` will get include in your `Resource.Designer.cs`**

If you look in your Android SDK folder (And have included Extras: Android Support Repository) for the file `attrs.xml`:

> android-sdk\extras\android\support\design\res\values\attrs.xml

You will be able to search this file for the `headerLayout` declare-styleable attribute. When you include the Design Support Library all the various XML tag will be referenced into constants you can then make use of in your code behind.

Comment: At first I didn't have Xamarin.Android.Support.Design installed, but now it is and I am still getting the error. Any ideas?

Comment: I checked that the android-sdk has the attrs.xml file and contains the headerLayout attribute. I have even tried delening the Resource.Designer.cs file and when it is recreated, it still doesn't work. Is there some way to view a trace of the tool that populates the Resource.Designer.cs file as it is being generated? I know it can work on my computer because I downloaded https://github.com/suchithm/NavigationDrawerMD and got it to run on my computer.

Comment: hmm, trying to think of what else could be the issue. If you comment out the headerLayout attribute in your XML does the app compile?

Comment: @enantiomer2000, can you also check your references and see it 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design' is included?

Comment: @enantiomer2000, another place you can check is your `<user>\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.Design\` folder to make sure that the correct version of the library you are referencing is available. You would normally get a different error as far as I remember if this was the issue, but atleast we will be able to rule it.

Comment: I am marking PlaceHold3r answer as correct because he did inform me that I needed to include the Design Support Library. As for what was going on afterwards, I am not sure. To fix it, I opened up the Nuget package manager for my project and just updated every project to the latest. After this, the Resource.Designer got all of the Design Support Library attributes.  Thanks for the help.